# "It is black, it is not blue" or "It is black. It is not blue"?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization

I am not sure if I have to add capital letter and a period (full stop) in the following sentence. Obviously, I am talking about cases where I say them continuously, and in that case I'm not sure if they are considered as one or two sentences.

> It is not green **,** **i**t is blue.

or

> It is not green **.** **I**t is blue.

Comment: A dot that's used to terminate a sentence is called a *period* in American English, and *full stop* in British English.

Comment: I'd say "It is blue; not green" if I'm in a conversation. This is more comfortable to say (at least for me).

Answer (score 6):

Two sentences, and you should read about "comma splices". If you care about details, you can join the sentences either with a full stop or with a semicolon: "It's black; it's not blue."  The semicolon indicates that the sentences are closely related.

If you don't care about details, it really doesn't matter much outside of English tests. Comma splices are common in casual written English.

Comment: 1+ for the answer. If I understood the comma splices is a mistake when two parts of a sentence are connected by comma only without any logic. Isn't it? Second, If I understood you, in formal letters for example I can choose between full stop and semicolon. Correct?

Comment: A comma splice is when you join two sentences with a comma. "It is not green , it is blue." is a comma splice.

Comment: I frequently use comma splices in my casual writing, they are a convenient way to link two related ideas without the dreaded semicolon.  ;)